# SQL assertion on 2 tables

Tags: sql

> Assume that there are 2 tables R(a) and S(a). Using a general SQL
>   assertion, express that S.a is a foreign key referencing R.a. That is,
>   there should not be any S.a value that does not appear in R.a.

I have the above question in a quiz, which i failed to secure any marks. Can anyone shine some light on this? Really keen to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE S (
    a INT
    CONSTRAINT FK_S_R FOREIGN KEY (a)
        REFERENCES R (a)
        ON DELETE CASCADE --optional
        ON UPDATE CASCADE --optional
)
```

Comment: your answer is not an sql assertion no?

Comment: it is sql. specifically the tsql flavor. what do you mean by sql 'assertion' ?